# И всë-таки, как расставить знаки?

Tags: пунктуация

Второй раз.

`Мне в ВК (?) а (?) точнее (?) не мне, а моему другу (?) написал мошенник.`

Подскажите, как расставить знаки (перечислите ВСЕ варианты) и обязательно объясните почему.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Правильно **(один вариант):**

*Мне в ВК — **а точнее, не мне, а моему другу,** — написал мошенник.*

Два тире, вторая запятая относится к **вставной** конструкции.

***А точнее*** — вводное слово.

Comment: А почему запятая перед тире?

Comment: К вставке относится.   ВСТАВКА: А точнее . А дальше обособленное уточнение (как именно точнее?).